# How to push an object to the dict state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to push an object to the state.

I created a function for this. This function should copy the first state object and add it to the end of the state.

```
addField() {
    const index = (this.state?.fields.length) -1
    const newFields = [...this.state?.fields[index]]

    console.log("newFields", newFields) // [    {        "key": "input_field_name",        "value": "This is a value 4"    },    {        "key": "field_name",        "value": "field name's value 4"    },    {        "key": "datatype",        "value": "text"    },    {        "key": "Datatype",        "value": "Label 4"    }]

       
    this.setState(
  { 
    fields: [[...this.state.fields[index]], newFields],
  },
  () => {
    console.log("updated state", this.state);
  }
);
console.log("state: ", this.state)
```

}

This is my state:

```
fields: IFieldDefinition[][];
  activeFields: {
    key: number;
    fields: IFieldDefinition[];
  };
```

[image: this.state]

**Updated code:**

Now, when I run the function, it creates *a new state* from the last object of the state instead of add.

how can I fix that?

Comment: What's the type of `newFields`? BTW, `fields` is an array, you tried to set it as object.

Comment: Right, you just need to replace the `{}` around `fields` with `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields` is an array, so you cannot assign values as an object with `{}`

If you want to add that new state to the end of the state, you can use the below approach

```
const index = (this.state?.fields.length) - 1
const newFields = [...this.state?.fields[index]];

//if the current index is matched with which field you want to update
this.setState(
  {
    fields: this.state.fields.map((currentValue, currentIndex) =>
      currentIndex === index ? [...currentValue, ...newFields] : currentValue
    ),
  },
  () => {
    console.log("updated state", this.state);
  }
);
console.log("state: ", this.state);
```

Comment: I update my code and question, can you check it?

Comment: I just modified my answer too, hopefully, it's helpful :D @edche

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the 0th index data and move it to the end of the array
if so

```js
let a={A:[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]}
let temp=a.A.shift()
a.A.push(temp)
setState({...a})
```